# Why is there a great difference in run times of pow() and ** while taking modulus in python?

Tags: python-3.x, pow

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
c = (2**100000000) % 1000000007
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)

start_time = time.time()
c = pow(2, 100000000, 1000000007)
end_time = time.time()
print(end_time - start_time)
```

This is the output result:

> 0.5842893123626709
>
> 0.0

But if I dont take mod, the run times are almost same.

What is the reason for such difference in the run time when we are performing the same operation?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: That's because the first operation will calculate `2**100000000` first and then take its modulo. The second operation will do it using a direct formula as @Loocid cited.

Comment: Can you clarify why you expect them to be the same operation? The first is exponentiation *followed by* modulo, the second is modulo exponentiation. Are you asking what is the algorithmic difference between the two?